# Count blocks in a series

Tags: r, vector, count

This is a simple problem, however I cannot find an elegant solution for:

Given is the following vector series:

```
 series=c(1,2,4,5,6,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,2,4)
```

I now want to count blocks of this vector in the same vector; e.g. if I have a block size of 2, I would like to count the pairs 1&2, 2&4, 4&5 and so on (in total 8 unique blocks if I did the counting right).

Can you think of an easy way to program that so that I receive an output matrix with a column for the "unique block number" and a corresponding column for the counts?

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to can use `rollapply` from `zoo`,

```
nrow(unique(rollapply(series, 2, by = 1, paste0)))
#[1] 8
```

You can change '2' to get combinations(block sizes) of 3, 4, etc...